# Create Multiple Tasks in Locust

Tags: python-3.x, load-testing, locust

I want to run multiple load tests from Locust e.g. testing the front end and the backend. I was wondering if I could do this from a single locust file but pass which test I want to run as argument in `locust -f locustfile.py --host=<host>`.

Comment: Honestly Speaking, I am unable to understand exactly what you mean to say.
Are you expecting to run both backend and frontend from same file ? Is that file contains functions which carry out that activity ?
NOt sure if it will help but you can check out this link - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085387/is-there-any-way-where-i-can-send-host-value-as-a-parameter-in-locust

Answer (score 1):

Use the @task decorator it will run each example code is here

```
# The multiple uer login script with - https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.org

from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet,task,between

class UserBehaviour(TaskSet):

    @task(1)
    def login_post(self):
        print("from user 1 logining in")
        resp = self.client.post("/index.php/auth/login",data={"action": "process","userName": "Admin","password": "admin123" , "_csrf_token": " f28bb18622cc82a56c41be5f7de07690"})
        print(resp.status_code)
    @task(1)
    def load_dashboard(self):
        print("from user 2")
        resp = self.client.get("/webres_5f61a473615588.75870608/orangehrmDashboardPlugin/js/graph-visualizer/pie-chart.js")
        self.client.get("/webres_5f61a473615588.75870608/orangehrmDashboardPlugin/js/flot/JUMFlot.min.js")
        self.client.get("/webres_5f61a473615588.75870608/orangehrmDashboardPlugin/js/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js")
        self.client.get("/index.php/dashboard/employeeDistribution")
        print(resp.status_code)
    @task(1)
    def apply_leave(self):
        print("from user 3")
        resp = self.client.get("/index.php/leave/getWorkWeekAjax?_=1602164350152")
        self.client.get("/index.php/leave/getHolidayAjax?year=2020&_=1602164350151")
        self.client.get("/index.php/leave/getLeaveBalanceAjax?&leaveType=1&startDate=yyyy-mm-dd&endDate=yyyy-mm-dd")
        self.client.get("/index.php/leave/getLeaveBalanceAjax?&leaveType=1&startDate=2020-10-09&endDate=2020-10-09")
        self.client.get("/index.php/leave/getLeaveBalanceAjax?&leaveType=1&startDate=2020-10-09&endDate=2020-10-16")
        print(resp.status_code)

        
                                      


class User(HttpUser):
    tasks=[UserBehaviour]
    wait_time = between(5000, 10000)
    host="https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com"
```