# Is there any way where I can send host value as a parameter in locust?

Tags: locust

I would like to know if there is any way with which i can send host value as parameter. I am aware that locust provides a paramter, "--host" which can help here but it's not working for me. 
This is my code implementation -

```
class NcsoTest(TaskSet):

    REQ_HEADER = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content-Length": "860",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.21.0",
     }

    @task(1)
    def send_post_request(self):
        response = self.client.post("/api/v2/services", data=Singleton.json_body, headers=NcsoTest.REQ_HEADER)
        print response


class NcsoLoad(HttpLocust):

    max_wait = 300
    min_wait = 300
    sleep_time = 10

    task_set = NcsoTest
```

I am using this command to run locust.
pipenv run locust -f testsuite/playground/locust_create_ics_host_flow.py --master --no-web --clients=1 --hatch-rate=1 --host=https://10.247.123.172 --run-time=1m

I tried multiple approaches but host value is not propagated and picked up in self.client.post.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hmm... I cant see why this wouldnt work. Are you using a recent version of locust? If locust doesnt get the host param (and there is no host specified in the locust) it shouldnt even start. What is your output?

Comment: I am using locust v13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to send host value to my program by using host parameter from outside the script.
Here are the two commands I used through shell script and passed values for :

```
./run_locust_host.sh --locust_file testsuite/host/locust_host_flow_task.py --host https://10.123.123.123 --min_wait_time 300 --max_wait_time 300 --num_clients 1 --hatch_rate 1 --test_time 2m
```

this script parses all the details and assigns the value to respective locust parameter.

Inside the script (py file), Its able to pick up host value and execute below post request.

```
response = self.client.post("/api/v2/services", data=Singleton.json_body, headers=NcsoTest.REQ_HEADER, verify=False)
```

My earlier request was working but failing since I did not specify "verify=False" in post request which led me to believe that host value is not propagated.

Comment: Hi! It is great that you solved the issue! I think the symptoms stated in your question dont really map to what was your problem. Could you edit the question to more closely match what was actually your problem & accept your own answer? Or just delete/vote to close the question.

Comment: Helpful. In my case I used locust --host https://test.test.test --users 10 --hatch-rate 2 --run-time=1m --headless

Answer (score 3):

There are three options to accomplish what you are asking about. The first option is to change the host entry parameter by removing the equal sign.

from

```
--host=https://10.247.123.172
```

to

```
--host https://10.247.123.172
```

In the second option, edit your test file and add a host entry as listed below.

```
testsuite/playground/locust_create_ics_host_flow.py  

class NcsoLoad(HttpLocust):  
    host = "https://10.247.123.172"  
    max_wait = 300  
    min_wait = 300  
    sleep_time = 10 
    task_set = NcsoTest
```

Use either option, but not both at the same time. It may cause confusion on down the road. The host entries for options one and two are required to display the host site at the web UI while running tests. Not using a host entry will produce a "None" value at the web UI. Not a big deal unless working with customers while testing or using the "--no-web" option in your original post.

The last option is really cool and provides more flexibility when writing test cases. More information is provided in the link below.

```
# Support for tests that use multiple hosts  
https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/150
```

One more thing to consider. Remove all of the "=" since they're not required in each parameter.

from

```
locust -f testsuite/playground/locust_create_ics_host_flow.py --master --no-web --clients=1 --hatch-rate=1 --host=https://10.247.123.172 --run-time=1m
```

to

```
locust --locustfile testsuite/playground/locust_create_ics_host_flow.py --master --no-web --clients 1 --hatch-rate 1 --host https://10.247.123.172 --run-time 1m
```

From the "The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters"

```
>>> import this  
Explicit is better than implicit.
```

Hope this information is helpful.

Regards,

Comment: Sending parameter from outside is the base requirement, so second option becomes invalid as for first option of removing "=" , yes I am doing the same, its just that I forgot to edit it here.
But, the fact remains is, i am unable to send host info properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a config.py file like this:

```
class EnvSettings(object):

 host_url = 'http://test.com/'
```

Then from your locust class, you can import

```
host = EnvSettings.host_url
```

Comment: Initially, I did attempt in similar manner but we needed an approach with which we can send the host value from outside and not explicitly change everytime. Thus we wrote a script with which we can send necessary parameters to locust as command.

Comment: @Seema Nair  Pl look into this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120975/how-to-invoke-a-grpc-python-client-in-locust