# How to invoke a GRPC python client in locust?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grpc, locust, grpc-python

Is there any way to invoke  GRPC python client in locust.

The output is generated when I run the code `locust -f 1.py`. But the stats are not working. They are idle.

users are swarming, but the stats are idle for everything

Answer (score 2):

When you build your own client you need to report samples to locust yourself (because how would it otherwise know what you had done?)

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html

To report a sample, you need to do something like this (if you're calling this from a TaskSet - if you are already in the User class, skip the .user part):

```
self.user.environment.events.request_success.fire(request_type="grpc", name=name, response_time=total_time_calculated_by_you, response_length=your_response_length)
```

In pre-1.0 locust you'd do something like:

```
from locust import events,
events.request_success.fire(request_type="grpc", name=name, response_time=total_time_calculated_by_you, response_length=your_response_length)
```